# Photoshop CC2017 brush stroke disappear and colorwheel stuck on screen

Tags: windows-10, display, adobe-photoshop, lag

Since a few weeks, Photoshop CC2017 is "lagging" behind in a weird way.

- The color wheel stays stuck on the screen until I draw a brush stroke.
- When drawing a brush stroke, a whole chunk will disappear visually until I draw a second brush stroke.

This happens regardless of which brush I am using.
My laptop is rather powerful and hard disks are far from being full (so I don't believe it can come from scratch disks)

Thank you for your help

Edit : Thank you for your answers, just updated to 2019, nice update indeed but it doesn't help with my problem =/ exactly the same still...
here is an exemple of my problem
https://gfycat.com/densemediocreirrawaddydolphin

Comment: First suggestion would be to update to the current CC 2019, which you can do right from the CC desktop app. There is no support for CC 2017 any more, so no-one is checking compatibility to latest Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Photoshop CC 2017
2. Reboot laptop
3. Install Photoshop CC 2019